# Create table with duplicate records?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have identified duplicate records in my staging environment

```
SQL> SELECT COUNT(*) 
  2  FROM MASTER_CHILD_MERGE A 
  3  WHERE  A.CAM_ID IN (SELECT B.CAM_ID FROM CAM_DIM B);
SQL> 703022
```

For the analyst in our team, I want to create a table that has A and B's columns. I tried doing that

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE DUPES AS 
  2  SELECT * FROM NDS_MASTER_CHILD_MERGE A  
  3  WHERE  A.CAM_ID IN (SELECT B.CAM_ID FROM CAM_DIM B);
```

but I realized that it will only gives me A's columns. How do I add B's columns as well? I am pretty sure it is an obvious solution but I am not seeing it...

I am on Oracle 10g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join those two tables

```
create table dupes as 
  select * 
   from nds_master_child_merge a
   join cam_dim b 
     on a.can_id = b.cam_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.*, B.* INTO DUPES
FROM NDS_MASTER_CHILD_MERGE AS A INNER JOIN CAM_DIM AS B ON A.CAM_ID = B.CAM_ID
```